# HP Proliant DL360p Gen8 server faulty hard disk replacement

Tags: linux, hp-proliant, raid10

I had a faulty disk on my HP Proliant DL360p Gen8, which has p420i controller and Raid10, and spare replaced the faulty one automatically. OS is RedHat 6. I want to do hot swapping work to install new disk in the server.

My question is that, what other operation is needed to replace the hard disk？
Like “# zpool replace c1t2d0 c1t3d0” command in Solaris.

The new disk will be built automatically or manually?

```
  #hpacucli ctrl all show config
  Smart Array P420i in Slot 0 (Embedded) 
  array A (SAS, Unused Space: 0  MB)
  logicaldrive 1 (279.4 GB, RAID 1, OK)

  physicaldrive 1I:1:1 (port 1I:box 1:bay 1, SAS, 300 GB, OK)
  physicaldrive 1I:1:2 (port 1I:box 1:bay 2, SAS, 300 GB, OK)
  physicaldrive 1I:1:3 (port 1I:box 1:bay 3, SAS, 300 GB, OK, spare)

  array B (SAS, Unused Space: 0  MB)
  logicaldrive 2 (558.7 GB, RAID 1+0, OK)
  physicaldrive 1I:1:4 (port 1I:box 1:bay 4, SAS, 300 GB, OK)
  physicaldrive 2I:1:5 (port 2I:box 1:bay 5, SAS, 300 GB, OK)
  physicaldrive 2I:1:6 (port 2I:box 1:bay 6, SAS, 300 GB, OK)
  physicaldrive 2I:1:7 (port 2I:box 1:bay 7, SAS, 300 GB, Failed)
  physicaldrive 2I:1:8 (port 2I:box 1:bay 8, SAS, 300 GB, OK, active spare)
```

Thanks.

BR

Answer (score 1):

Remove the bad disk. Replace it with the new disk.

**That is all.**

You don't have to take any other action.

---

The drive will even tell you which disk(s) to remove and what NOT to remove:

See: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PYYRAB17f4s